# Very Very simple function to hide and show EditBox CURSOR

Tags: c, winapi

I wonder how I can make a simple function to make the cursor appear and disappear from the EditBox, a simple function where I pass the HWND of the window and the name of the EditBox only to disappear and the appear the cursor ?

Thanks (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [HideCaret()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648403.aspx) and [ShowCaret()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648406.aspx) ?